# Get all dates between two dates retrieved from a string and make a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like the following:

```
#CI[20131229]CO[20131231]PV1,#CI[20130918]CO[20130919]PV3,#CI[20131009]CO[20131011]PV3,#CI[20131226]CO[20140103]PV4,#CI[20131226]CO[20140103]PV3
```

.... list goes on with same format. Format is:

```
,# = entry seperator
CI[YYYYMMDD] = Check In Date
CO[YYYYMMDD] = Check Out Date
PVx = Room Number
```

I want to get all dates within the check in and checkout EXCEPT the checkin checkout date and put to string like this (if it was the above string):

```
#20131230PV1,#20131010PV3,#20131227PV3,#20131228PV3,#20131229PV3,#20131230PV3,#20131231PV3,#20140101PV3,#20140102PV3
```

I needed to retrieve CheckIn dates and Checkout dates seperately
That I managed to did successfully with this:

```
bookcaldatesci.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/CO[^\]]+\]/ig, "");
bookcaldatesci.innerHTML = bookcaldatesci.innerHTML.replace(/CI\[/ig, "");
bookcaldatesci.innerHTML = bookcaldatesci.innerHTML.replace(/\]/ig, "");
bookcaldatesco.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/CI[^\]]+\]/g, "");
bookcaldatesco.innerHTML = bookcaldatesco.innerHTML.replace(/CO\[/ig, "");
bookcaldatesco.innerHTML = bookcaldatesco.innerHTML.replace(/\]/ig, "");
jQuery.noConflict();
$(bookcaldatesci.innerHTML).css({'background-image':'url("img/booked.jpg")','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position-y':'100%','background-size':'100% 50%'});
$(bookcaldatesco.innerHTML).css({'background-image':'url("img/booked.jpg")','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-size':'100% 50%'});
```

But to add up dates between the date range I'm a bit lost..

(I GOT THE ANSWER: TO CHECK, CHECK MY ANSWER BELOW)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Great problem description. You just forgot to mention what you've tried so far and what difficulties you encountered with your code. Oh and by the way, you forgot to show the code you've tried. I invite you to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decompose the problem into two sub-problems:

1. Parsing your string into an object with two dates and a room number.
2. Finding the days between two given dates.

For the first sub-problem you can use regular expressions and the Date object constructor.

```
function parseDate(date) {
    return new Date(date.substring(0,4), date.substring(4,6)-1, date.substring(6,8));
}

var input = '#CI[20131229]CO[20131231]PV1,#CI[20130918]CO[20130919]PV3,#CI[20131009]CO[20131011]PV3,#CI[20131226]CO[20140103]PV4,#CI[20131226]CO[20140103]PV3';

var regExp  = /CI\[(\d{8})\]CO\[(\d{8})\](PV\d)/g;
var items = [];
var match = regExp.exec(input);
while(match != null) {
    items.push({
        ci : parseDate(match[1]),
        co : parseDate(match[2]),
        room : match[3]
    });
    match = regExp.exec(input);
}
```

For the second sub-problem you can use a loop to generate all the days between two dates:

```
function daysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
    var days = [], current = startDate;
    while(current <= endDate) {
        days.push(current);
        current = new Date(current.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you have made. Can I know how can I get the result for part II?

`document.getElementById('resultdiv').innerHTML = daysBetween('20/06/2013', '30/06/2013');`

gives nothing.

Comment: use the Date object : daysBetween(new Date(2013, 5, 20), new Date(2013, 5, 30)); (Months are 0 based)

Comment: Thanks all for the replies I have used all the replies to construct the answer which I posted below :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a date difference between each check in and check out and do a for loop using that value. So for 1 to that value, and just add the for value to the check in date for the whole loop. Easiest way to navigate each set of check in check out dates may be either using regex or a loop based on finding string values.

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave a good idea for me. I should proceed with that.

Comment: you're welcome! glad I could help. If you want I could try and write up a code example if you want.

Comment: Thanks you for the replies I have used all the replies to construct the answer which I posted below :)

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trying I figured the answer. It will produce the following result:

```
#30122013PV1,#10102013PV1,#27122013PV1,#28122013PV1,#29122013PV1,#30122013PV1,#31122013PV1,#112014PV1,#212014PV1,#27122013PV1,#28122013PV1,#29122013PV1,#30122013PV1,#31122013PV1,#112014PV1,#212014PV1,
```

This is the code

```
<div id=oo></div>
<div id=pp>#CI[20131229]CO[20131231]PV1,#CI[20130918]CO[20130919]PV3,#CI[20131009]CO[20131011]PV3,#CI[20131226]CO[20140103]PV4,#CI[20131226]CO[20140103]PV3</div>

<script>

function daysBetween(startDate, endDate , roomNum) {
var days = [], current = startDate;
current.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()-1);
while(current <= endDate) {
var d0 = new Date(current);
var d1 = d0.getDate();
var d2 = d0.getMonth()+1
var d3 = d0.getFullYear()
var d4 = roomNum
oo.innerHTML = oo.innerHTML + "#" + d1 + "" + d2 + "" + d3 + "" + d4 + ",";
days.push(current);
    current = new Date(current.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));   

}
return days + "," + roomNum;
}

function parseDate(date) {
return new Date(date.substring(0,4), date.substring(4,6)-1, date.substring(6,8));
}


var input = pp.innerHTML;
var regExp  = /CI\[(\d{8})\]CO\[(\d{8})\](PV\d)/g;
var items = [];
var match = regExp.exec(input);
while(match != null) {
items.push({
    ci : parseDate(match[1]),
    co : parseDate(match[2]),
    room : match[3]
});

match = regExp.exec(input);

}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
daysBetween(new Date(items[i]['ci']), new Date(items[i]['co']), items[0]['room']);
}


</script>
```